# How to use pd.json_normalize() on a column formatted as string representation of a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large file that is read into a DataFrame which has a column 'features' which is a string representation of a list. The elements in this "list" are sometimes strings, sometimes numbers, as shown below, but the lists in reality at times may be very long depending on the data source.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', -5]",
                   "['a', 'b', 1, 2, 4, 'd', 3]",
                   "['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', -5]"],
                  columns=['features'])

df
                       features
0  ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', -5]
1  ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 4, 'd', 3]
2  ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', -5]

# Looking at first two characters in first row for example--
df.features[0][0:2]
"['"
```

I am trying to use pd.json_normalize() to get the column into a "flat table" so it is easier to perform operations on various elements in the features column, (not all of them, but different sets of them depending on the operation being done). However, I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.

How can I use json_normalize() properly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

above you are setting the items as a list of strings.  What you should be doing is setting them as a list of arrays.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'features' : [['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', -5],
                   ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 4, 'd', 3],
                   ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', -5]]})
```

will give you

```
    features
0   [a, b, 1, 2, 3, c, -5]
1   [a, b, 1, 2, 4, d, 3]
2   [a, b, 1, 2, 3, c, -5]
```

Notice the missing quotes around the characters?

so you want `df.features[0][0:2]`

you get

```
['a', 'b']
```

Now how are you getting the data for your dataframe?

or if you have to get your dataframe like that,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', -5]",
                   "['a', 'b', 1, 2, 4, 'd', 3]",
                   "['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', -5]"],
                  columns=['features'])

df.features = df.features.str.replace(']','').str.replace('[','').str.replace(' ','').str.replace("'",'').str.split(',')
```

then `df.features[0][0:2]`

will give you

```
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: The DataFrame I am working with is already provided in this format -- I have intentionally placed those quotes in the example to illustrate the situation. It is rather unusual I agree.

Comment: I added a simplistic way to convert between the formats.  I am not sure that it would work with bigger data

Comment: Thanks for your edit! this works quite well